# Ccavenue Payment in US dollars

Tags: php, ccavenue

Can any tell me how to process the transaction in USD in Ccavenue page. In my website users can buy a product in INR or USD. So if a user select USD then i need to process the users transaction in USD. How can i do that? When i pass the US dollar value to ccavenue payment page it is getting converted to INR.

Is there any parameter is should pass to get the currency value in ccavenue page in USD.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the CCAvenue account with International Transactions enabled. AFAIK, there are two kinds of CCAvenue accounts

Comment: I want to show the customer price in dollars on the billing page. Can I do it in ccavenue???